# When to use in Kendo UI Data-Source and Observable to show Data in a Template

Tags: javascript, templates, data-binding, kendo-ui, telerik

Here I have sample code which shows an autocomplete in two ways.

```
<div data-role="view" data-model="foo">
    <div>
    An autocomplete widget
    <input data-role="autocomplete" data-source="['foo', 'bar', 'baz']" />
    </div>

    <div>
    A widget bound to the mobile view ViewModel dataSource field
    <input data-role="autocomplete" data-bind="source: dataSource" />
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var foo = kendo.observable({
        dataSource: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
    });

    new kendo.mobile.Application();
</script>
```

When do I have to use the observable, and when do I have to use the DataSource? I don't get the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are confused is because, in your example, you aren't using a Kendo UI `DataSource` object at all. Both of your examples are simple `ObservableObjects`. To create a `DataSource` you would actually have to instantiate a variable using the `kendo.data.DataSource()` function.

> `ObservableObjects` support change tracking and notify any subscribers when a change occurs.
>
> Items of the `DataSource` are `ObservableObject` instances.

[Kendo API Reference: ObservableObject](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject)

[Kendo API Reference: DataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource)

Comment: oh okay, That means i also could use just the observable Objects, because it "inherits" it.